# relative clause "of which" vs. "which"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([What type of adverbs “ideally” is?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240994/109190)) I said

> there are at least 10 different types of adverbs **and these are** manner, place, time, duration, frequency, degree, focusing, certainty/obligation, viewpoint, evaluative.

I guess the sentence above is idiomatic. How about this one

> there are at least 10 different types of adverbs, **which are** manner, place, time, duration, frequency, degree, focusing, certainty/obligation, viewpoint, evaluative.

and this one

> there are at least 10 different types of adverbs, **of which are** manner, place, time, duration, frequency, degree, focusing, certainty/obligation, viewpoint, evaluative.

I guess I am confused by genitive case. So, I learned a [tutorial](https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clauses-8.html), here are some examples from there.

> He bought a car, the brand name **of which** I can't remember.
>
> He bought a car, **which** I can't remember the brand name **of**.

"which" is substituted for "the car" in "the brand name **of the car**"

I guess I've understood the rule in the car example.

However, I still don't know the answer to types-of-adverbs question, could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is idiomatic. Note that it consists of two independent clauses connected by "and". You could just as well delete the "and" and insert a period, making two sentences out of it.  The only flaw I see is that "adverb" should be singular.

You are trying to make a subordinate clause of the second independent clause.

Your second example doesn't work properly because "which" should connect to "types", but it tries to connect to "adverbs". Using the singular "adverb" helps this because "which are" then must connect to "types".   A re-casting also would help that misconnection:
"Adverbs are of ten different types, which are..." , followed by the list.

Your third example, using "of which", is incorrect because the original sentence is equating "types" to a complete list. There is no place for "of which".
That phrase could work in a sentence like this:
"Adverbs come in ten different types, of which 'manner' and 'place' are two examples."

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. In you last example "Adverbs come in ten different types, of which 'manner' and 'place' are two examples", `which` refer to "types", right?

Comment: You are a really excellent contributor. Thank you, that's very kind of you.
 Regarding the singular-plural part, would you please take a look at [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241211/109190)?

Comment: "...refers to types" Yes, that's right.

Comment: As to singular/plural, I prefer singular, but in any case, if you have a choice, the singular helps to clarify the reference.

Comment: I disagree that the second example is wrong.  "which are ..." is attached to the noun phrase "types of adverbs".  If we rearrange that into a simple statement, it becomes "types of adverbs are manner, place, ...", which is perfectly grammatically correct, so there's no reason the subordinate clause form isn't also correct (and it sounds fine to me too).